# Jquery form submission not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, debugging

I'm new to JavaScript. I have been trying to design some code which geocodes a location when a search button is hit and the submits the form if successful. To make it to slightly more complicated, if an option from the autosuggest is selected, it also geocodes it even before the search button is hit.

This all seems to work, except that the form is never submitted and I can't figure out why.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/42/

```
$(function () {
  var input = $("#loc"),
      lat   = $("#lat"),
      lng   = $("#lng"),
      lastQuery  = null,
      lastResult = null, // new!
      autocomplete;
  
  function processLocation(query, callback) { // accept a callback argument
    var query = $.trim(input.val()),
        geocoder;
  
    // if query is empty or the same as last time...
    if( !query || query == lastQuery ) {
      callback(lastResult); // send the same result as before
      return; // and stop here
    }
  
    lastQuery = query; // store for next time
  
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: query }, function(results, status) {
      if( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        lastResult = true; // success!
      } else {
        alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
        lastResult = false; // failure!
      }
      callback(lastResult); // send the result back
    });
  }
  
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
    types: ["geocode"],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: "uk"
    }
  });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);
  
  $('#searchform').on('submit', function (event) {
    var form = this;
    
    event.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
    
    processLocation(function (success) {
      if( success ) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
        form.submit()
      }
    });
    
  });
});
```

Comment: have you do console.log() anywhere to see exactly where your code breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling:

```
processLocation(function (success) {
```

But your processLocation has the callback on the second parameter:

```
function processLocation(query, callback)
```

Try removing the query parameter from processLocation:

```
function processLocation(callback)
```

**OR** call it with a blank argument:

```
processLocation(null, function (success)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, is it incorrect for me to have the callback in the second param?

Comment: yes, it's incorrect to have the callback in the second parameter if you're only passing in 1 parameter. You have specified 2 parameters in processLocation(), but you're only passing one. So your function that you're passing that you intend to be the callback, is being passed in as the query parameter.

Comment: @Jimmy do you plan on passing in query anywhere?  it seems you want to pass it in but have a local variable with the same name? `function processLocation(query, callback) { // accept a callback argument
    var query = $.trim(input.val()),`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to integrate your first suggestion but a straight swap seems to break it, as shown here. http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/48/ I think I am missing the point

Comment: @wirey I don't know if it needs to be passed to be honest, I was helped with this bit of the code, I am not sure it is necessary???

Comment: you declared `processLocation(query, callback)`.. so you called `processLocation(function(){// your code})` ..  so your function is getting passed in as `query` the first param `processLocation(query`<--

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you all for he help